# On PostBackUrl property of a button, send only specific control instead of all controls to the previous page of destination page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

The question is simple, When we use PostBackUrl property from source page and go to destination page, on destination page, we can access all the controls of source page on destination page by using PreviousPage property.

My question is: Is it possible to send only specific control instead of all controls from source page to destination page. The core purpose is optimization. My source page has more than 300 controls. I want to send only one specific control instead of all those 300 controls to the destination page, Is it possible? Thanx in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Ajax ?

I think you should google for Viewstate, Partial PostBacks and UpdatePanels.

Take a look here too: [What is a Partial Postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238651/what-is-a-partial-postback)